# The meaning and the usage of the expression "Don't you dare"

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

To me, "Don't you dare!" is an expression that communicates a warning to someone. For instance:

> - **Don't you dare** talk to me like that!
> - **Don't you dare** follow me! (ete...)

But I wonder if you could paraphrase these examples with so that I could understand the precise meaning that appears to your minds after hearing this structure.

I think it can have two different meanings, (but I'm not sure):

> 1. You don't have the right to....
> 2. If you have enough courage, ...

I wonder how does it sound to you?

Please note that I have read the [similar thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162297/whats-the-difference-between-don-t-you-dare-and-you-dont-dare) on the forum   three times before posting my question, but as you know and all the dictionaries have mentioned, the two expressions "dare I say" and "I dare say" are two completely different statements with some AFAIC possible overlaps which I think that they should be analyzed differently with separated examples.

Meanwhile, comparing the two expressions: "don't you dare" and "don't you worry" in the addressed link above doesn't make any sense to me!

The only point that was close to my interpretation was @James k's one where he had mentioned that the construction at hand has a connotation of:

> - How dare you behave that way.

Moreover, I need to know whether it is common in current English these days? Also, Americans use it too or it is more of a British term?

Also, Michael R mentioned in his answer that:

> The expression "don't you dare do something" is just a variant, is an emphatic way to say **don't even think about trying to do that**.

But how much streas and emphasis?!

To discover these all, I think paraphrasing the examples would be the best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "don’t you dare" and "you don't dare"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162297/whats-the-difference-between-don-t-you-dare-and-you-dont-dare)

Comment: A-friend, this is a good question but I suspect the reason you're not getting a lot of answers is that what you are asking isn't exactly jumping off the page! :-) You have a couple of *wonderings*, and a *need to know* as well as a *how much*, not to mention a mild suggestion about *paraphrasing*. Perhaps you could pull your narrative together into a summary list of questions, as specific as you can make them? (But keep the narrative too - it's good for context.)

Comment: Actually, I've just read the edit history. Other than the addition of the comment that you have already seen the other thread, I think your first form of the question was better. It's certainly easier to get the gist of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit suggestion that to do X ("*Don't you dare X...*") will provoke a negative reaction from the speaker; to do X is considered wrong by them. It isn't encouraging the receiver to do the thing but trying to strongly discourage them.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that doing whatever thing it is that you don't want the person to do would require some *daring, cheek* or *effrontery.* It's a warning not to risk doing it because it would make you very angry and perhaps result in them being punished.